# How to return XML from only a small number of endpoints?

Tags: c#, refit

I'm using Refit and it works fine as most of my server endpoints return JSON. However, I have a couple of endpoints that return XML.

Is it possible to change Refit's `ContentSerializer` at runtime for specific endpoints?

Comment: The Content-Type HTTP header will indicate the type.  So you can check the header and then determine which serialize method to use.